# Xamarin forms android application showing un-usual behavior and crashing

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Recently around Dec 1st reset my pc and installed visual studio. Previously when I last installed visual studio, it showed Xamarin forms in the installation directory. This time it showed MAUI and provided Xamarin as an addon to work with Xamarin. Until this its fine. After installation, I was able to load Xamarin forms project properly. Now, when I deploy to the android device for debugging, everything worked fine. But as I interacted more, UI started misbehaving with stack layout or frame view elements not resizing.

**Below screen shots will explain the situation**

1. Normal Behavior
   [image]
2. Parent page for the above page
   [image]
3. When interacting with the page in the first picture, elements like stack layout and frame are not resizing.
   [image]
4. When navigated from the current page to parent page, UI misbehavior continues
   [image]
5. When clicked on an item in the above page, instead of getting page that looks like 1st pic, getting empty page
   [image]
6. When navigated back still same mal-formed page
   [image]
7. On turning off and on the screen, UI refreshing to normal.(Before any crash happens)
   [image]

While the above process happens, anytime application is crashing particularly when any data was being updated on the UI.

**Debug Logs when crashed**
[image]
[image]

I presume this is a Xamarin renderer or some library issues. How do I over come this as my app is in production stage.

I tried to reinstall entire visual studio and also cleared all the cache of Xamarin and Android like NuGet packages etc. It the same result. A workaround would be good and a solution would be excellent.

Comment: Impossible to say from the given information. However, if you are testing on a device or simulator that already had an older version of the app, its important to "start clean". If emulator, do Factory Reset. If a physical device, delete app from it (old incompatible debug info may still be there), then Restart (Power Off/On) device.

Comment: If that doesn't fix, then the problem is on the pc (Visual Studio + Xamarin + Android SDK).   How long ago did you start building this Xamarin project? Less than six months? Greater than two years? There's no "silver bullet" to resolve all the issues you list. You will have to pick ONE problem, on ONE page, and attempt to isolate it. Could be Xamarin version. Could be Android version. Could be a compatibility issue with any nuget package...

Comment: ... To isolate the cause of one problem, there are two approaches to consider. One is to disable most of your code, so as little as possible is going on. Find the exact code that, when removed, makes the problem go away. That's a clue to investigate further. The other approach is to create a new blank Xamarin project. Copy over enough code to test this one problem. If it works in the new project, then compare .csproj of old and new. What is different? BOTTOM LINE: There is no "workaround". There is no general "solution". You will have to isolate the cause of each problem.

Comment: I left out one early step, that might fix the situation. Do you have source code in a repository? If so, create a NEW SOLUTION FOLDER. Download source code to it. This should ONLY be source code (and any data). The minimum required to rebuild your app. There may be something in the old solution folder that is somehow obsolete. (Probably inside hidden `.vs` folder, so maybe you could just delete that, as well as ALL .bin and .obj folders throughout your solution.)

Comment: Ok, I will try to isolate the issue. Thank you.